# Help In Understanding These Statesments In Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax, lambda

What is the meaning of these statements in Haskell:

```
a)
(\x -> x + 1)

b)
 (\x -> x - 2)

c)
(\x -> mod (x * 3) 5)
```

I understand the x + 1, mod(x  * 3) 5 etc but the  \x before those statements makes them difficult for me to understand.

thanks for your help

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587157/question-about-the-two-haskell-symbols-and-what-they-do-and

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\` and `->` define a lambda (you could call it an inline function or a nameless function). So `\x->x` is the same as `\ x -> x` is the same as a function which returns its argument. And `\x y -> x + y` is a function which returns the sum of its two arguments.

Comment: Please notice, that the correct syntax in haskell would be `\x y -> x + y`.