# Question about the two haskell symbols and what they do: $ and \

Tags: haskell, syntax

Can someone explain to me with simple words what those two operators do:

```
$

\
```

Comment: The backslash is a symbol with special meaning in particular contexts.  `$` is a function defined in the [prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Base.html#%24).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787543/haskell-what-is-the-difference-between-dollar-and-dollar-exclamation-poi

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`\` is not an operator, it is part of the literal syntax. More precisely, it is part of *two* literal syntaxes: it denotes a lambda literal and it serves as an escape character in string literals.

The operator `$` is defined in the prelude as

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $ x = f x
```

In other words, it does *exactly* the same thing as whitespace does, namely just plain function application. *However*, while function application is left-associative and has high precedence (the highest, in fact), `$` is right-associative and has low precedence.

This allows you to omit parentheses when you have chains like "`f` applied to `g` applied to `h` applied to `x`", which without the `$` operator would be written like

```
f (g (h x))
```

but with the operator can be written as

```
f $ g $ h x
```

It is also useful if you want to pass the function application operator itself as an argument to another function. Say, you have list of functions and a list of values and you want to apply every function in the list to the corresponding value in the other list:

```
zipWith ($) fs xs
```

Answer (score 7):

> what those two operators do: $ \

The first one, `($)`, is an operator, defined as:

```
-- | Application operator.  This operator is redundant, since ordinary
-- application @(f x)@ means the same as @(f '$' x)@. However, '$' has
-- low, right-associative binding precedence, so it sometimes allows
-- parentheses to be omitted; for example:
--
-- >     f $ g $ h x  =  f (g (h x))
--
-- It is also useful in higher-order situations, such as @'map' ('$' 0) xs@,
-- or @'Data.List.zipWith' ('$') fs xs@.

($)                     :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $ x                   =  f x
```

It allows you to write functions with fewer parenthesese.

The second token, `\` is part of the Haskell syntax for [lambda abstractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#Haskell) -- anonymous functions.

So, e.g.

```
\x -> x + 1
```

is a function that will add 1 to its argument. The syntax for lambda abstractions is [described in the Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-260003.3).

Answer (score 2):

($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
base Prelude, base Data.Function
Application operator. This operator is redundant, since ordinary application (f x) means the same as (f $ x). However, $ has low, right-associative binding precedence, so it sometimes allows parentheses to be omitted;

keyword \
The backslash "\" is used in multiline strings > "foo\ > \bar" > in lambda functions > > \x -> x + 1